# Qt vulkan classes not defined during make on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, vulkan

I have been trying to compile a Qt/Vulkan project that works fine on Linux, on Windows. I am using QtCreator, Qt (5.11.0), and MingW.

I can **qmake** without problems, but **make** crashes with errors for each reference to a QVulkan* class, such as "not defined in this scope", but seems to have found and included the headers for that class.
I have tried compiling the qt vulkan examples, and got the same problem.
I ran configure -v, and found :

```
Qt Gui:
  Vulkan ................................. yes
```

Here is an example of a header that crashes :

```
#ifndef WINDU_H
#define WINDU_H

#include <QWindow>
#include <QVulkanInstance>
#include <QVulkanFunctions>
#include <QVulkanDeviceFunctions>

class Windu : public QWindow {
public :
    Windu();
    ~Windu();

    void render();
    void start();
    void reset();

    QVulkanInstance inst;
    QVulkanFunctions* vki;
    QVulkanDeviceFunctions* vkd;

};

#endif
```

I have stripped it down to the important : this gives not defined errors for *QWindow*, *QVulkanInstance*, *QVulkanFunctions*, *QVulkanDeviceFunctions*.

I have tried building qtgui separately, but it also crashes because it can't find Qt OpenGLES sources files.

I don't know much about C++ on windows.

This is my .pro file :

```
SHADERS = $$files(*.comp, true)
SHADERS += $$files(*.frag, true)
SHADERS += $$files(*.vert, true)

spirv.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.spv
spirv.commands = glslangValidator -V ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
spirv.depends = $$SHADERS
spirv.input = SHADERS
spirv.variable_out = COMPILED_SHADERS
spirv.CONFIG = target_predeps

SOURCES = $$files(*.cpp, true)
HEADERS = $$files(*.h, true)

# install
target.path = build
target.depends = spirv

DESTDIR=bin #Target file directory
OBJECTS_DIR=build #Intermediate object files directory
MOC_DIR=build #Intermediate moc files directory

CONFIG+=debug
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += spirv
```

and here is the repo if needed :
https://github.com/Paul-Hubert/fantastic-octree/blob/master/fantastic-octree.pro

Comment: What does your `.pro` file look like?

Comment: @Botje I have edited it in, however although my .pro is atypical, I cannot build the qt examples, so it shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: I tink you forgot to add `QT += gui` somewhere in your .pro file

Comment: Nevermind .. QT includes `gui` by default. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that on Windows, the only way to get the Vulkan classes is to build Qt yourself. I had done this, but something i had done wrong made the build unuseable. You have to build the sources as described here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html, and use that to build the project. I added a kit in QtCreator to do this.